# Ubuntu Crashes after apt update, probably Graphics driver issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, 22.04

I have Nvidia 1070 as my graphics card and I seem to constantly have issue in Ubuntu 22.04 at certain times:

1. When I click on Suspend in Wayland, after coming back in some time, when display is turned on it's all completely pixelated and off-colored, with almost unresponsive display apart from the cursor.

I tried to downgrade/change my nvidia graphics driver to a 300 range one, and opt-out of Wayland, it seemed to work. But then:

2. Whenever I try sudo apt-get update and upgrade, the Nvidia drivers also seem to upgrade. And today while doing so, during upgrade my screen got completely blacked out for half a minute and then I forced shut down my PC to restart it. It displays as of now.

Would like some help as I am unable to resolve it and by mistake I may update and upgrade again.

Comment: When the driver upgrades, it is actually being rebuilt (assuming you installed it from Ubuntu repos).  That rebuild may take several minutes.  If screen goes black, check from a virtual term (ctrl+alt+F3) login and run top to see if the update is still running. Sometimes a phase upgrade will mess up the rebuild  -- wait a day or so or force the upgrade (several answers here on phased updates).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)